# How to do a loop on all unchecked items from checkedlistbox C#?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, checkedlistbox

I was working on a method and then I realized that I had a foreach loop that ran through all checkedItems, instead of running through all unchecked item.

```
foreach ( object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{(...)}
```

I was wondering if there is way to do this without changing the code too much.
Regards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two options:

1. Loop through all `Items` and check them against the `CheckedItems`.
2. Use LINQ.

**Option 1**

```
foreach (object item in checkedListBox1.Items)
{
  if (!checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains(item))
  {
    // your code
  }
}
```

**Option 2**

```
IEnumerable<object> notChecked = (from object item in checkedListBox1.Items
                                  where !checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Contains(item)
                                  select item);

foreach (object item in notChecked)
{
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the items as a CheckBox enumerable then you can loop:

```
foreach (CheckBox cb in checkedListBox1.Items.Cast<CheckBox>())
{
    if (!cb.Checked)
    {
        // your logic
    }
}
```